# Trying to complete Google foo.bar level 3 (queue_to_do) and keep exceeding time limit

Tags: python, algorithm, xor

Honestly, I don't think my code is so bad.... This is the fifth version that I've come up with and I think it's the best so far.... But when I run the test on the foo.bar console it says "Time limit exceeded"

Do you see a way that I can make this faster? I'm at a loss for now.....

here's the README:

> ## Queue To Do
>
> You're almost ready to make your move to destroy the LAMBCHOP doomsday
>   device, but the security checkpoints that guard the underlying systems
>   of the LAMBCHOP are going to be a problem. You were able to take one
>   down without tripping any alarms, which is great! Except that as
>   Commander Lambda's assistant, you've learned that the checkpoints are
>   about to come under automated review, which means that your sabotage
>   will be discovered and your cover blown - unless you can trick the
>   automated review system.
>
> To trick the system, you'll need to write a program to return the same
>   security checksum that the guards would have after they would have
>   checked all the workers through. Fortunately, Commander Lambda's
>   desire for efficiency won't allow for hours-long lines, so the
>   checkpoint guards have found ways to quicken the pass-through rate.
>   Instead of checking each and every worker coming through, the guards
>   instead go over everyone in line while noting their security IDs, then
>   allow the line to fill back up. Once they've done that they go over
>   the line again, this time leaving off the last worker. They continue
>   doing this, leaving off one more worker from the line each time but
>   recording the security IDs of those they do check, until they skip the
>   entire line, at which point they XOR the IDs of all the workers they
>   noted into a checksum and then take off for lunch. Fortunately, the
>   workers' orderly nature causes them to always line up in numerical
>   order without any gaps.
>
> For example, if the first worker in line has ID 0 and the security
>   checkpoint line holds three workers, the process would look like this:
>   0 1 2 / 3 4 / 5 6 / 7 8 where the guards' XOR (^) checksum is
>   0^1^2^3^4^6 == 2.
>
> Likewise, if the first worker has ID 17 and the checkpoint holds four
>   workers, the process would look like: 17 18 19 20 / 21 22 23 / 24 25
>   26 / 27 28 29 / 30 31 32 which produces the checksum
>   17^18^19^20^21^22^23^25^26^29 == 14.
>
> All worker IDs (including the first worker) are between 0 and
>   2000000000 inclusive, and the checkpoint line will always be at least
>   1 worker long.
>
> With this information, write a function answer(start, length) that
>   will cover for the missing security checkpoint by outputting the same
>   checksum the guards would normally submit before lunch. You have just
>   enough time to find out the ID of the first worker to be checked
>   (start) and the length of the line (length) before the automatic
>   review occurs, so your program must generate the proper checksum with
>   just those two values.
>
> ## Languages
>
> To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py To provide a Java
>   solution, edit solution.java
>
> ## Test cases
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) start = 0
>       (int) length = 3 Output:
>       (int) 2
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) start = 17
>       (int) length = 4 Output:
>       (int) 14
>
> Use verify [file] to test your solution and see how it does. When you
>   are finished editing your code, use submit [file] to submit your
>   answer. If your solution passes the test cases, it will be removed
>   from your home folder.

And my solution:

```
def answer(start, length):
    f = 0
    r = 0
    while f < length:
        for i in range(start, (start+length) - f):
            r ^= i
        f += 1
        start = range(start, start+length)[-1] + 1
    return r
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hint 1

The XOR 5^6^7^8 is equal to the XOR(1^2^3^4^5^6^7^8)^(1^2^3^4).

In other words, you should concentrate on finding a function that is the xor of the first n natural numbers, and you can then use this function to find the xor of any range of integers.

### Hint 2

To find the xor of the first n natural numbers, consider the binary representation:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Concentrate on a single bit position and think about the pattern you get when you compute the xor of all the numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much. 

This will take a minute to digest.